# Erro ao Acessar Site em Hospedagem Terra

Tags: laravel, htaccess, hospedagem

Transferi um site para rede em uma hospedagem do Terra e ao tentar acessá-lo exibe o seguinte erro:

> Not Found [CFN #0005]

Estou conversando com o suporte - horrível, diga-se de passagem (Neto) - e eles dizem que é a minha programação que está errada.

Pedem pra verificar os arquivos e o `.htaccess`.
Estou usando Laravel:

Meu `.htaccess` está assim na raiz:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Eu faço isso para acessar o site sem usar o **/public** na URL.

E dentro da pasta **public** tem outro `.htaccess`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Esse `.htaccess` é o próprio Laravel que faz.

E ainda persiste o erro. Já chequei as permissões e estão todas em 755 ou RX.

Comment: Você tinha algum admin no seu sistema que configurava uso de permalink?

Comment: Não sei o que é Permalink. É coisa do Wordpress ?

Comment: Você está usando Wordpress??

Comment: Não estou. Laravel.

Comment: Este não parece ser um erro do seu Webserver (que pra usar .htaccess deve ser Apache) nem tampouco de permissões. Parece um erro do seu sistema. Aparentemente ele esperava encontrar o destino no diretório configurado anteriormente. Como o index parece ter sido processado, as regras de reescrita parecem ter funcionado normalmente. Sugiro começar a investigação pelo processamento da index.
Altere o arquivo index.php para ver se ele realmente o está processando. Um simples `die("AQUI");` já basta.

Comment: Então, o pior é que eu descobri que o Terra só tem o PHP 5.2. E o Laravel 5.0 só funciona a partir do 5.4. É horrível. Horrível. E eles não podem alterar a versão do meu PHP senão altera de todos os clientes deles.

Comment: Ai não funciona mesmo

Answer (score 4):

Eu tive problema com hospedagem terra com esse mesmo erro e consegui resolver com o seguinte código:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase  /novo/

Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

RewriteBase /novo/ é a pasta onde o site estava. Se estiver na raiz, basta colocar: RewriteBase /

Fonte: https://duvidas.terra.com.br/duvidas/8887/como-habilito-urls-amigaveis-em-minha-hospedagem